# Is it Possible to set "Windows On-Screen Keyboard" as an input in sg.InputText field ( PySimpleGUI)?

Tags: input, text, keyboard, virtual, pysimplegui

Dears,

Is it Possible to set "Windows On-Screen Keyboard"  as an input in sg.InputText field?

Thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oqzrz.png) ==> The Code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHNhw.png) ==> Desired Output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DByL.png) ==> Split Keyboard to lines using "Menu Option"

Comment: In Windows, press CTRL+Win+O to show the on-screen keyboard, do nothing and it will work as an input for `sg.InputText` element.

Comment: Thanks Jason, It's Working fine , but there are some special characters not appearing, that's why I want to insert my own key board, IN fact I have find some scripts and I'm able to create that, but I'm failing to insert that class to my project.
Here's the Link found for that : https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Touch_Keyboard.py

Comment: Dear @JasonYang, any idea about implementing this part in my project ? 
as I've explained the keyboard i want to use has some sepcial characters and not windows keyboard that can be opened by "CTRL+Win+O" as you said...I have created it based on this forum topic: https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Touch_Keyboard.py  .Thanks

Comment: Any code to demo your question ?

Comment: Sure, it will be better, I will share it in a while

Comment: Please find an updated input above explained in picture format. Thx

Comment: It will be better if you post you code in text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the demo code for you. Some functions for backspace key not built under PySimpleGUI, so tkinter code is required, like `element.widget`. The event for button `'OK'` not included here. You can replace the keyboard string with yours.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

keys = ["QWERTYUIOP", "ASDFGHJKL", "ZXCVBNM"]
chars = ''.join(keys)
lines = list(map(list, keys))
lines[0] += ["\u232B", "Esc"]
col = [[sg.Push()] + [sg.Button(key) for key in line] + [sg.Push()] for line in lines]

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Username"), sg.Push(), sg.Input(key="Username")],
    [sg.Text("Password"), sg.Push(), sg.Input(key="Password")],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button("OK"), sg.Button("Cancel"),sg.Push(), sg.Button("Keyboard")],
    [sg.pin(sg.Column(col, visible=False, expand_x=True, key='Column', metadata=False), expand_x=True)],
]

window = sg.Window('ACCESS', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, "Cancel"):
        break
    elif event == "Keyboard":
        visible = window["Column"].metadata = not window["Column"].metadata
        window["Column"].update(visible=visible)
    elif event in chars:
        element = window.find_element_with_focus()
        if isinstance(element, sg.Input):
            if element.widget.select_present():
                element.widget.delete(sg.tk.SEL_FIRST, sg.tk.SEL_LAST)
            element.widget.insert(sg.tk.INSERT, event)
    elif event == "\u232B":
        element = window.find_element_with_focus()
        if element.widget.select_present():
            element.widget.delete(sg.tk.SEL_FIRST, sg.tk.SEL_LAST)
        else:
            insert = element.widget.index(sg.tk.INSERT)
            if insert > 0:
                element.widget.delete(insert-1, insert)

window.close()
```

[image]

With `MenuOption` element, there's option `enable_events`, so tkinter call required here. There are three-line different keyboard, so each `Column` element for each keyboard line.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def callback(var, index, mode):
    window.write_event_value("Optionmenu", window['Optionmenu'].TKStringVar.get())

keys = ["QWERTYUIOP", "ASDFGHJKL", "ZXCVBNM"]
chars = ''.join(keys)
lines = list(map(list, keys))
lines[0] += ["\u232B", "Esc"]

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Username"), sg.Push(), sg.Input(key="Username")],
    [sg.Text("Password"), sg.Push(), sg.Input(key="Password")],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button("OK"), sg.Button("Cancel"),sg.Push(), sg.OptionMenu([f"Keyboard Line {i+1}" for i in range(3)], key='Optionmenu')],
    [sg.Column([[sg.Push()] + [sg.Button(key) for key in line] + [sg.Push()]], key=f"Keyboard Line {i+1}", expand_x=True, visible=False) for i, line in enumerate(lines)],
]

window = sg.Window('ACCESS', layout, finalize=True)
window['Optionmenu'].TKStringVar.trace("w", callback)   # enable events
keyboard = None

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, "Cancel"):
        break
    elif event == "Optionmenu":
        if keyboard is not None:
            window[keyboard].update(visible=False)
        keyboard = values["Optionmenu"]
        window[keyboard].update(visible=True)
    elif event in chars:
        element = window.find_element_with_focus()
        if isinstance(element, sg.Input):
            if element.widget.select_present():
                element.widget.delete(sg.tk.SEL_FIRST, sg.tk.SEL_LAST)
            element.widget.insert(sg.tk.INSERT, event)
    elif event == "\u232B":
        element = window.find_element_with_focus()
        if element.widget.select_present():
            element.widget.delete(sg.tk.SEL_FIRST, sg.tk.SEL_LAST)
        else:
            insert = element.widget.index(sg.tk.INSERT)
            if insert > 0:
                element.widget.delete(insert-1, insert)

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent JOB @Jason Yan....This is what I need exactly and seems I miss the info on adding "tkinter code ...need to learn more, and by the way , Is there any good reference on how to deal with classes, events.....Thanks again

Comment: Hello @Jason , Sorry to bother you again, I need one of the 2 Options :
1- How to add menu option in "Keyboard" button to select only one row ? or 
2- how to change the color of line ? If 1st option not possible
Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't understand what the questions here.

Comment: My Keyboards contains many keys, So I want to show line by line only from "Keyboard" key as shown in attached picture . Check above "Split Keyboard to lines using "Menu Option"

Comment: Updated as above.

Comment: Excellent !!!! as expected. Thanks a lot @Jason...See you in another topic :)

Comment: Hi @ Jason Yang, I see "ESC" Key is not working ? What should be the reason. Thx

Comment: Did you read the code and understand what function for each statement ? There's no event handler for `'Esc'`, should do it by yourself.

Comment: Sure, I read all statement one by one, It should be fine from your side , this one should be an easy task I will add it . Thanks